# How to view/debug Ajax requests made from WinJS in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winjs

Is there any way in Visual Studio to view the network activity of a WinJS app?  There is a DOM explorer, and I can set breakpoints in the JavaScript, but I haven't been able to find an equivalent of Chrome's Network tab or anything like that to see Ajax requests being made.